# cant back to OnActivityResult

Tags: android, onactivityresult

hey guys i wanted to back to onActivityResult in previous activity

here is my code

```
public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                            Intent i = new Intent(DetailPhotoMedical.this, MedicalClaim.class);
                            Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                           // i.putExtra("photo", "");
                            extras.putString("photo","");
                            extras.putString("photoNo",photoNo);
                            i.putExtras(extras);
                            setResult(1000, i);
                            finish();
                        }
```

and i want to back to previous activity in onActivityResult

```
 protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode==1000)
    {
        Intent ii = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = ii.getExtras();
        photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo");
        photoNo = extras.getString("photoNo");
        if (photoNo=="photo1")
        {
            strPhoto1="";
            ivAttachment1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        }

    }
```

here is code to intent the 2nd acitvity

```
Intent i = new Intent(MedicalClaim.this, DetailPhotoMedical.class);

               /* i.putExtra("photo", strPhoto1);*/
                Bundle extras = new Bundle();
                extras.putString("photo", strPhoto1);
                extras.putString("photoNo","photo1");
                i.putExtras(extras);
                i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);
```

but the OnActivityResult didnt catch my resultcode

can you tell me whereis the wrong?

thx

Comment: Replace your Intent i = new Intent(DetailPhotoMedical.this, MedicalClaim.class); with Intent i = new Intent(); may be it work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. 
You should describe more clearly about your case:

1. `OnActivityResult` is not called.
2. `OnActivityResult` is called, but the `resultCode` is not 1000.
3. `OnActivityResult` is called, `resultCode` = 1000 but you cannot get extra data.

For 2 first cases please make sure that you called `startActivityForResult()`.

For 3rd case please remove this line  `Intent ii = getIntent();` and use the `Intent` which is input parameter of `onActivityResult`.

Comment: ive edited my post, but hwo to use StartActivityForResult() ?

Answer (score 1):

For calling 2nd activity using intent, use

> startActivityForResult(i)

instead of

> startActivity(i)

dont use

> i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

unless you know the consequences of using it and for getting intent in onActivityResult use

> data

variable passed as a parameter in

> onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)

something like this

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

if(resultCode==1000)
{
    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo");
    photoNo = extras.getString("photoNo");
    if (photoNo=="photo1")
    {
        strPhoto1="";
        ivAttachment1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    }

}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for upvoting the answer, if it solved your problem please accept it as a correct answer. Ty

Answer (score 0):

Its happening because you are getting data from different `Intent`.

This,

```
if(resultCode==100){
    Intent ii = getIntent();
    Bundle extras = ii.getExtras();
    photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo");
    photoNo = extras.getString("photoNo");
    if (photoNo=="photo1") {
        strPhoto1="";
        ivAttachment1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    }
}
```

Sohuld be like this.

```
if(resultCode==100){

    Bundle extras = data.getExtras();
    photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo");
    photoNo = extras.getString("photoNo");
    if (photoNo=="photo1") {
        strPhoto1="";
        ivAttachment1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
    }
}
```

Where you can see `data` in an intent given in `onResultActivity`'s parameters.

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
     .
     .
     .
}
```

**EDIT :** make sure you are using `StartActivityForResult();` for calling Activity.

I hope this will help you out.

Comment: You probably has to CAST the incoming data to String using toString() method in photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo").toString();

Comment: no need because he is already putting extras as string `extras.putString("photo","");`

Answer (score 0):

The code are you using for catch the result is wrong, you should use something like this:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if(resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) //Here is where you need to do the change
    {
        Intent ii = getIntent();
        Bundle extras = ii.getExtras();
        photoFromDetail = extras.getString("photo");
        photoNo = extras.getString("photoNo");
        if (photoNo=="photo1")
        {
            strPhoto1="";
            ivAttachment1.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_menu_camera);
        }

    }
```

Because you compare a wrong parameter you always has `false` in your if

Hope this help you

Answer (score 0):

finally it solve,

just using statActivityForResult()

and remove i.getintet and use data.getExtras